# Determine equation of cone of view of an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, 3d, quadrics

Given the ellipsoid

$ (p - C)^T Q (p - C) = 1 \tag{1}$

where $ C $ is the center of the sphere, $p $ is a point on the ellipsoid surface, and $Q$ is a $3\times3$ symmetric and positive definite matrix. Given also a point $A$ outside the ellipsoid.  I would like to determine the equation of the cone of view of the ellipsoid from point $A$.  That is, I want to determine the equation of the cone whose vertex is at $A$ and tangent to the ellipsoid.  This is the question.

**My effort:**

We want the gradient vector at point $p$ which is on the ellipsoid surface to be normal to the vector $(p - A) $, i.e.

$ (p - A)^T (p - C) = 0 \tag{2}$

Combined with $(1)$, this gives the points $p$ of tangency on the ellipsoid.

This doesn't seem to work.

So instead, suppose you have a ray from $A$ in a direction $V$, then this ray is given by

$ r = A + t V $

I want this ray to be tangent to the sphere.  Substitute this into the equation of the ellipsoid, and derive the condition that will make the intersection one and only one.

$ (A + t V - C)^T Q (A + t V - C) = 1$

Expanding,

$ t^2 (V^T Q V) + 2 t V^T Q (A - C) + (A - C)^T Q (A - C) - 1 = 0 $

For this quadratic equation to have a single real root we must have the discriminant equal to zero.  Hence, the condition on $V$ is that

$ ( V^T Q (A - C) )^2 - ( (A - C)^T Q (A - C) - 1) (V^T Q V) = 0 $

and using simple manipulation, this can be written as a quadratic form,

$ V^T Q_c V = 0 $

where

$ Q_c = Q (A - C) (A - C)^T Q - ( (A - C)^T Q (A - C) - 1 ) Q $

But $ V =  \dfrac{1}{t} ( r - A ) $

Therefore, the equation of the cone is

$ (r - A)^T Q_c (r - A) = 0 $

This seems correct.

I've implemented an example on [this SAGE page](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlkd1qhDAQhe8XfIe58y-GTGKiXvgkS1usFSu4q7hW1KfvxB8qFG_OJCffOYMzW9jKxnwqBs-d98H1nVvVQg6CSx3M7xJCkjpYDoV06q2R9mmOAJ1b2T0rskeSa4XHExowTfZHEXLUhi7WjaCCOVgikIHgsbGeOVgJJG1EsIZqfziHqT0IUfLUQjcL8iRF5dwmQXlTVY7d4N2ppoxlljFbOMuE0QxibqRBk77RLhNezJHgJlapYkAqzhJhmO2qjMJkM8urGblREpUlJ4LK6j2DCNlmtl5BK5Xdyxt9CICyQng1z2OSzq0mT_Po26Zsxo--7Ub15VUtA29mEeG0T3KhDqdeKYIBCtJl13ZD7rZN_T1-tj-Vy6DrC-IsxEQGxaunovkdGX22Tw3h_zD7d864I-1UW9Y1qhuKZ33Jybk-sX0xFI9qHJryBMNEiHGrK2nZvoE_0FB9ueyEIFjIL65EnNg=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), where

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} 0.25 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0.5 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0.125 \end{bmatrix} $ and $C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}$

And,

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

The tangency curve (which is an ellipse) is also shown in red.

Your comments, or alternative solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: It's well developed in analytic geometry.  See my posts [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395472/equations-of-tangents-to-an-ellipse/4395655#4395655) and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880013/enveloping-cone-of-an-ellipsoid-with-vertex-p-has-parabolic-sections-by-plane/2882879#2882879).

Comment: Also [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940885/find-the-locus-of-the-vertices-of-the-right-circular-cones-that-pass-through-the/1952340#1952340) and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329166/when-is-the-projection-of-an-ellipsoid-a-circle/4338236#4338236).

Comment: @NgChungTak Thanks for that.

Comment: ... and [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4243507/1257), with references.